# Does a Christian have a responsibility to participate in government?

Tags: biblical-basis, civil-government

I have heard it said many times that it is the responsibility of Christian to participate in their government, specifically that **every Christian has the responsibility to vote**. Is there some biblical justification for this belief? I know that the government of the US is dramatically different than what existed in Biblical times, but is there some precedent set forward by scripture that would validate this?

I am wondering about the US system of government specifically, as it is largely based around citizen participation, and as an American.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no Biblical imperative for us to participate in government in the way you describe.  The New Testament doesn't say much about our relationship with government, because the emphasis is on our membership in Christ.  We are to be less concerned with things of the world, and more concerned with the things of God.

Here's what the Bible does say about our relationship to government:

**Give to Caesar what is Caesar's**

> **[Luke 20:22-25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2020:22-25&version=ESV)** (ESV)
>   <sup>22</sup>  Is it lawful for us to give  tribute to  Caesar, or not?” <sup>23</sup>  But he perceived their  craftiness, and said to them, <sup>24</sup>  “Show me  a denarius. Whose likeness and inscription does it have?” They said, “Caesar's.” <sup>25</sup>  He said to them, “Then  render to Caesar the things that are Caesar's, and to God the things that are God's.”

Jesus is saying here that since we do live under the authority of a human government, we ought to honor that authority.  This is not an imperative to participate in government, but it is an imperative to obey our government (when it does not conflict with our obedience to God, of course).  In this case, Jesus is referring to paying taxes, but I believe that the principle applies to honoring government laws and regulations in general.

**Submit to authorities**

> **[1 Peter 2:13-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20peter%202:13-15&version=ESV)** (ESV)
>   <sup>13</sup>   Be subject for the Lord's sake to every human institution, whether it be to the emperor as supreme, <sup>14</sup>  or to governors as sent by him  to punish those who do evil and  to praise those who do good. <sup>15</sup>  For this is the will of God,  that by doing good you should put to silence the ignorance of foolish people.
>
> **[Romans 13:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%2013:1&version=ESV)** (ESV)
>   13 Let every person  be subject to the governing authorities. For  there is no authority except from God, and those that exist have been instituted by God.

Again, we ought to submit to authorities.  And again, there is no indication here that we ought to participate in government - only that we ought to submit to it.

**Our true citizenship is in heaven**

> **[Philippians 3:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=philippians%203:20&version=ESV)** (ESV)
>   <sup>20</sup>  But  our citizenship is in heaven, and  from it we  await a Savior, the Lord Jesus Christ,

Although we are under the authority of earthly governments, we ought to remember that our true citizenship is in heaven.  Participation in earthly government, while acceptable, should not be our focus.

Comment: I especially appreciate the distinction between submitting and participating.

Comment: Was there any way for the Jews to participate in government during Christ's life? Perhaps he never told them to because it wasn't possible. The lack of exhortation does not imply lack of importance.  If our government was considering removing our right to practice Christianity, would it not be important enough to focus on?

Comment: @JustinY, if that were the case, I would probably be more inclined to participate more heavily in government (though I'd say enduring through persecution is more important than preventing it).  But I still don't think it's the right area to focus on, and I still don't think "every Christian has the responsibility to vote".  Whether or not we individually feel we ought to vote, the Church's focus needs to be on the Gospel, growing in conformity to Christ, and bringing others to Christ.

Comment: @JustinY, today (at least in the U.S.), when Christians are urged to vote, it's usually for the purpose of legislating Christian values/morality onto the unbelieving population, keeping "one nation under God" in the pledge, etc.  Christianity can survive without injecting itself into government, and legislating Christian values does not solve people's sin problem.  Only the Gospel can do that.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Eric's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/7816/30), but I'm going to give a contrarian answer.

In Philippians 4: 8,9, we read:

> Finally, beloved, whatever is true, whatever is honourable, whatever is just, whatever is pure, whatever is pleasing, whatever is commendable, if there is any excellence and if there is anything worthy of praise, think about these things. Keep on doing the things that you have learned and received and heard and seen in me, and the God of peace will be with you.

Christ did not speak on every topic.  Peter and Paul did not speak on every topic.

While Paul does not specifically address participation in government in his letter to the Philippians, we can discern from what he did say that we ought to participate in art, literature, and yes, even government so that we can do our part to make these activities true, honorable, just, pure, pleasing, commendable, and excellent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything in the Bible that explicitly commands participation in government. While the idea of voting was known at the time -- Rome and parts of Greece were republics during periods that overlapped the Old Testament -- I don't know of any mention of it in the Bible.

On the other hand, the Bible does repeatedly command us to help orphans and widows, to fight injustice, and to defend the oppressed. Sometimes these good things can be done through government. More often government is the source of the evil, and by participating in goverment we can mitigate it. A number of people in the Bible were govenrment officials, like Joseph and Daniel and David, and it's clear they used these positions to further God's work.

So I think that applying general Biblical principles would lead us to the conclusion that Christians should participate in government when there is an opportunity to do good. But I don't know of any specific command.

Comment: "More often government is the source of the evil" - just... seriously?

Comment: Well looked at from a global historical perspective, as would fit with the context of this question, then "more often government is the source of the evil" is probably pretty accurate. If you read it simply as a right-wing modern American thing, then sure there's plenty to articulate and debate.

Comment: @Marc Hitler, Stalin, Mao, Pol Pot ... yes, government has been a huge source of evil in the world.

Comment: @Jay if we're doing the counting that way, you could say the same of religion. On net, however, governments have been doing pretty well. What do you propose instead? Anarchy? Theocracy? Theonomy?

Comment: @Marc Well, we're off on a tangent here. But have governments ever done any good? Of course. But they've also done a lot of evil. Hitler's government killed about 25 million people. Stalin's killed 22 million. Mao's killed 50 million. Pol Pot's killed 2 million. (Which doesn't sound like as good a score as the others, but remember he only had 8 million to start with, as a percentage of a nation's population I think he's #1.) I don't know of any force in the world that has committed as many murders as governments. I don't have statistics for organized crime but I doubt it comes close. ...

Comment: ... The Spanish Inquisition killed 3000 to 4000 people over the course of 350+ years. That's horrible, of course, but Stalin would have been disappointed if a DAY went by in which he killed only 4000 people. No murders that can be pinned on a religious group begin to compare with what governments have done. The Ku Klux Klan killed about 1500 people. Amateurs.

Comment: That like arguing all people are bad because there are murderers. Rhetorical, but I notice you still don't cite alternatives. Because there are none except individualism and anarchy.

Comment: @Marc The original question was whether Christians should get involved in government. I said that Christians should attempt to influence government because it can be a source of good or a source of evil. I'm not sure how you got from "Christians should be involved in government to prevent it from doing evil" to "government should be abolished and replaced with anarchy".

Comment: BTW, A very wise man, who calls himself MarcGravell, posted on another thread, "Please see the plural in Hawking's quote. Presumably you agree with him in all but one case? 99.9% agreement yet you object with his sentiment?" So if I may apply his words here, "Please see the plural 'governments' in my quote. You concede that many governments have done evil things, but you object to the sentiment that government can be a force for evil?"

Comment: @Jay: I'm not going to speak for Marc, but I personally see a wide gulf between "government can be a force for evil" and "more often government is the source of the evil." The former recognizes that governments don't often live up to their best intentions; the latter says that *most* governments harm their citizens. That's the statement that appears in your answer, and it appears to me to be a gross overstatement.

Comment: @Bruce pretty much covered my reply for me, thanks.

Comment: @Bruce Well, this is christianity.stackexchange.com, not politics.stackexchange.com, so ... Anyway, I didn't say government is always evil or inherently evil. Quite the contrary I began by saying that it can do good. But I would think it's a simple, undeniable fact that governments often do evil, from the extremes of the Nazi Holocaust, the Gulag, etc, to the little crimes like taxing the poor to subsidize huge corporations. Do you think such things are trivialities that shouldn't concern us? Well, there's no factual basis on which to say how important they are.

Comment: @Jay: I don't disagree with what you are saying in the comments. My only objection is to the way it is phrased in your answer. Certainly the Holocaust and the Gulag were evil; on the other hand, those are not representative of the majority of government activity in the world. From the Allied resistance in World War II, to Lincoln's freeing the slaves, from foundational documents like the Magna Carta or the U.S. Costitution, to local services like fire departments and libraries, governments provide a wide range of benefits that many citizens take for granted.

Comment: To say, "**More often** government **is the source** of evil" is a gross overstatement. If you could find more appropriate phrases than the ones I've highlighted in bold, I wouldn't object.

Comment: Well, we're into politics here and not Christianity. So you're saying your problem with my statement is that you believe that governments do more good than harm? I don't know exactly how you'd measure that. Nazi Germany built the first modern highways. How many feet of road does it take to outweigh one murder? I certainly approve of the Allies fighting Germany in WW2 and Lincoln freeing the slaves, but those actions wouldn't have been necessary if other governments had not done great evil. The fact that one government managed to stop the evil that another government was doing doesn't give ...

Comment: ... give you a net plus, it just stops the accumulation of minuses. Likewise the point of the Magna Carta was to stop the abuses of the king. The governments of the Allies stopped the Nazis after they had killed 25 million people. If they had done nothing, the Nazis would no doubt have killed more. But the total score for Nazis plus Allies is still minus 25 million. ...

Comment: ... If the greatest good that you can credit governments with is that some governments mitigate the evil that other governments do so they STOP enslaving and murdering innocent people, that's not exactly a rousing endorsement of government as an institution.

Comment: "little crimes like taxing the poor" - when did taxation become a crime?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely; for if we don't we become complicit in the results and we can claim no authority to object to the actions of that government's rulers. Sure we can say there's a higher calling and it's heaven but to not participate, even so little as not voting is a poor witness at best; we in essence are throwing our support to the victor whether they're good or bad as the case may be. We must be part of the solution; not part of the problem. God didn't say to sit still, he called us to action.

> Be strong in the Lord and in the power of His might. Put on the whole armor of God, that you may be able to stand against the wiles of the devil. For we do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of the darkness of this age, against spiritual hosts of wickedness in the heavenly places.
>
> Therefore take up the whole armor of God, that you may be able to withstand in the evil day, and having done all, to stand. Stand therefore, having girded your waist with truth, having put on the breastplate of righteousness, and having shod your feet with the preparation of the gospel of peace; above all, taking the shield of faith with which you will be able to quench all the fiery darts of the wicked one.
>
> And take the helmet of salvation, and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God; praying always with all prayer and supplication in the Spirit, being watchful to this end with all perseverance and supplication for all the saints...."  Ephesians 6:10-18